# LDAP System Authentication in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I'm having a bit of an issue with system authentication against LDAP in Ubuntu.
The LDAP server is OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 10.10, and the client is Ubuntu 10.10 also. I've set up the client by following the "LDAP Authentication" steps at https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html

apt-get install libnss-ldap; auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap; pam-auth-update

I've done these steps on the server and been able to see LDAP users when running getent passwd. Doing the same steps on the client, getent passwd does not return any LDAP users.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf` is configured to use your server and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured to use ldap for lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping/access the ldap server from the client ? What about the other way around ?

You'll also want to make sure that ports 389 (ldap) or 636 (ldapSSL) are opened.
A tool like nmap (apt-get install nmap):

```
nmap <IP address> -p389 or
nmap <IP address> -p636
```

Will usually let you know if your ports are closed, filtered or opened.

Comment: I don't think it's a port problem. Using ldapsearch I can query the LDAP server and get a reply.